# Show image from link

Tags: html, image

Dear all I am new in the group. I had a little trouble. I have a link like this: http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q=html5,jquery&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=300
His function in to show an image of a chart.
How can I show the image on my page?
Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried this far. There are many answers for his already if you just search

Comment: Actually the source is not an image - it's a graph

Comment: Thanks. So how I can see it on my page?

Comment: google trends have an embed option that gives you the code to generate an iframe - http://www.geteverything.org/embed-google-trends-blog-website/

Comment: Have a look at this link it should explain how to embed trend data onto your site. https://support.google.com/trends/answer/4365538?hl=en

Comment: Thanks all for help

Answer (score 0):

`<img src = "...the address here..." alt = "alternative text if image can't be loaded" />`

Comment: Tomorrow I will check. But it's what I did with noresult. Only broken links

Comment: That would work,but the link he's provided is not an image.